# Show Parent & Sibling Categories

Tags: categories

My category group looks like this:

- car seats
- strollers

  - travel systems
- gear

  - walkers
  - swings
- nursery

When I'm on the URL `/products/category/gear`, I want to display:

- gear (here)

  - walkers
  - swings

When I'm on the URL `/products/category/walkers`, I *still* want to display:

- gear

  - walkers (here)
  - swings

I don't want to display the entire category group, just the current category's parent and/or children and/or siblings.

Comment: Probably GWcode Categories will not be enough. You also should give a look to GWcode CatMenue and GWcode HasChildren, eventually combining them. Link to GWcode-Addons-page: http://gwcode.com/add-ons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I ended up doing it:

I used an embedded template and passed the current category ID as a variable:

`{embed='_products/category_breadcrumb' cat_id='{if triggers:parent_cat_id_1}{triggers:parent_cat_id_1}{if:else}{triggers:cat_id_1}{/if}'}`

The Zoo Triggers variable returns blank if the current category has no parent (meaning it's a top-level category), so I had to use a conditional to output the category ID if the current category is top-level.

Then in my embedded template:

```
{exp:gwcode_categories
  cat_id='{embed:cat_id}'
  style='linear'
}
  {if results_total > 1}
    {if cat_count == 1}
      <p class="category-filter">
        View: 
    {/if}

    {if cat_url_title == triggers:segment_3}
      <span class="here">{if depth == 1}All{/if}{if depth == 2}{cat_name}{/if}</span>
    {/if}

    {if cat_url_title != triggers:segment_3}
      <span><a href="{path='products/category/{cat_url_title}'}">{if depth == 1}All{/if}{if depth == 2}{cat_name}{/if}</a></span>
    {/if}

    {if cat_count == results_total}
      </p>
    {/if}
  {/if}
{/exp:gwcode_categories}
```

The caveat is that it only works with a 2-level category tree, but that's all I need for my specific situation.

I'm using the [Zoo Triggers](http://goo.gl/19qOOd) `{triggers:parent_cat_id_1}` and `{triggers:cat_id_1}` variables, but you could do the same thing with [Low Seg2Cat](http://goo.gl/7dnWG) `{segment_1_category_parent_id}` and `{segment_1_category_id}` variables.

I also used an embedded template to get the parse order right, but I imagine you could use [Stash](http://goo.gl/NjiQD) for this too.

Answer (score 1):

I think [NSM Categories](http://ee-garage.com/nsm-categories), with its [target_category](http://ee-garage.com/nsm-categories/tag-reference#exp%3ansm_categories%3aarchive.parameters.target_category) param and [{category_is_target}](http://ee-garage.com/nsm-categories/tag-reference#toc-_exp_nsm_categories_archive_%3asingle_variables%3acategory_is_target) tag, could help. Also, [Seg2Cat](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat/docs) is useful for grabbing an ID from the category name in the URI.